# Change to vs Change with?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I have looked on the internet regarding this issue and could not find a definitive answer so I posted the question here.

Which one do I use if I want to **change something to something** else?

> Change that code **to** this code.

or

> Change that code **with** this code.

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, you would use "***to***" to show *transformation*

> Change that code **to** this code.
>   Change that Python code to this R code.

but as usual it depends what you want to say.

If you wanted to show *replacement*, you might use

> **Ex**change that *(piece)* of code **with** this *(piece)* of code.

If you want to say *how* to make a change happen (*by way of*), you might use

> You can **change** that French article to English **with** this translator.